# Tracing Shared Content in the facebook network

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, social-networking

I am fairly inexperienced with using the facebook api and was wondering whether there was any way to obtain the path some shared content takes across the network? One scenario that I am looking at is: say I would like to trace the path of a particular article, would it be possible with the help of the api, to determine the origin of the article on the network and the subsequent path the article takes across the network through user sharing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.